# Android - Make AppData Listed in DocumentsUI File Browser Menu

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Newer android >= 11 make it hard to access app data folder aka getExternalFilesDir(null)

But we can still access with internal file browser like com.android.documentsUi

by opening two window and spilt view. We can modify or move file by drag and drop.

When im using it, i found some application listed in Drawer Menu like shortcut, when touched it bring to AppData files. Is anyone know how to do it?

Here im not talking to mimic, its how Other Application can be showed in List drawer menu of Internal Android File Frowser.

[image: Showing Document UI drawer menu Image]

Comment: `Newer android make it hard to access app data folder aka getExternalFilesDir(null)` Well why not mention Android 11+?

Comment: `we can still access with internal file browser like com.android.documentsUi` Sorry, never heard about that. Where are you talking about,?

Comment: So its DocumentUI its system internal app,  not Files by Google. On some phone its hidden but Can be opened with intent or with help on playstore app to make shortcut to Activity like a com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity.

Comment: Well please post code of the intent to open it. Let us know where you are talking about

Comment: Im not asking about intent. If you look at the image link you will understand. You dont event know the documentUI

Comment: Indeed. Thats why i asked for intent code.

Comment: DocumentsUI is just the front end that provides user-level access to internal phone storage via SAF. It is present on every android device and apps usually use this when they want you to select a file for upload/ import or select a location for saving the app's own generated data. it usually acts as a file picker of sorts and is not displayed as a fully accessible user app.

Comment: `But we can still access with internal file browser like com.android.documentsUi` That is nonsense. No other app can access the getExternalFilesDir of other apps. What your post is about is only that you make a documents provider which serves getExternalFilesDir(). And the document provider is then visible and selectable with for instance ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or ACTION_OPEN_DICUMENT_TREE. Next time please write a less confusing post.

Comment: @blackapps I don't know what to say because you don't even know what DocumentUI is and how to work with it, anyway you can copy files to the folder in android/data or obb by creating a new window from DocumentsUI and performing SplitviewTop, then using Drag and Drop. It has permission android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS.
I asked about how an application can be displayed in the DocumentUI drawer menu, and instead of a helpful response, you provided irrelevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't blame anyone who doesn't understand the question because it's not popular, since people use third-party File Manager apps. However, users can experience this by using Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) and opening the drawer menu section.

So, I discovered that it has been documented on the Android developer site, and this method involves using a custom DocumentProvider class. By creating a CustomDocumentProvider, clients can view the files we share, in this case, through DocumentsUI listed in drawer menu.

Declare it in the AndroidManifest.

```
<manifest... >
    ...
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        ....
        <provider
            android:name="com.example.android.storageprovider.MyCloudProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.storageprovider.documents"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In the DocumentProvider class, declare the root path for sharing.

```
override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        rootDirectory = context!!.getExternalFilesDir(null) //external appdata
        return true
    }
```

Indeed, we can control when files can be shared by returning zero results in the queryRoots() method. This allows us to manage and restrict the sharing of files based on specific conditions or criteria.

```
override fun queryRoots(projection: Array<out String>): Cursor {
...
    // This removes our provider from the list entirely.
    if (!isAppRun()) {
        return result
    }
```

If the File Manager (DocumentsUI) app icon is not found in the app launcher, you can search the Play Store for a "File Shortcut" app. Alternatively, we can provide a programmatic solution to launch the DocumentsUI app. By using an Intent to explicitly open the DocumentsUI app.

```
private fun launchFileBrowser(){
        if (

            fileBrowserName("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                   ComponentName("com.android.documentsui","com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity"))
            || fileBrowserName("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                ComponentName("com.google.android.documentsui", "com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity"))
            || fileBrowserName("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                   ComponentName("com.android.documentsui","com.android.documentsui.FilesActivity"))
            || fileBrowserName("android.intent.action.VIEW", null)
            || fileBrowserName("android.provider.action.BROWSE", null)
            || fileBrowserName("android.provider.action.BROWSE_DOCUMENT_ROOT", null)) {
            return
        }
    }

private fun fileBrowserName(action: String?, componentName: ComponentName?): Boolean {
        val authority = BuildConfig.DOCUMENTS_AUTHORITY
        val rootUri = DocumentsContract.buildRootUri(authority, DocumentProvider.ROOT_ID)

        val intent = Intent(action, rootUri)
        if (componentName != null) {
            intent.setComponent(componentName)
        }
        return try {
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }
    }
```

Source:
[Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider)

Answer (score 0):

I had a difficult time understanding the question due to English perhaps not being your native language, but I hope the following answers your question somewhat:

After API 30, the function you mentioned will just return what you get by `getFilesDir()`.

Therefore accessing internal storage requires a different set of methods I had described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642726/java-io-filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eexist-file-exists-android-11/66645800#66645800).

As for those shortcuts, I'm guessing it was manually added by the DocumentsUI app. Perhaps those shortcuts are of only a *specific category* of app.

We can do this using PackageManager, listing the packages whose category matches with some metadata we shall provide along with our query to the PackageManager query methods. Using *the* instance of the aforementioned class, we can get app name, package id, icon, its openable intents, etc. Then we just hook the information up to whatever views we want accordingly.

For that, please refer to posts like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) and [official technical writeup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) regarding this.

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand the question either. But OP does not blame you as the post was not understandable. We blame OP.