# Trying to save image using API 31+ / Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: java, android

Worked prior to API 31.

Originally, the String filePath was

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/DCIM/Camera/spooky";
```

Which crashed the app - so I replaced it with the below code, the app does not crash but the file is not being saved anywhere.

```
public void buttonSaveImageClicked(View view) throws IOException {


    editorImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = editorImage.getDrawingCache();
    SaveLayoutToFile saveImage = new SaveLayoutToFile(this, bitmap, editorImage);
    String filePath = this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();


    saveImage.execute(filePath);
}
```

Also, the ability to save and share the image,

```
public File saveFileToShare() {
            try 
            {

                File fileImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/DCIM/Camera/attachment.png");
                if(!fileImage.exists())
                {
                    fileImage.delete();
                }
                editorImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = editorImage.getDrawingCache();
                fileImage.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileImage);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);                                        
                ostream.close();
                editorImage.invalidate();
                editorImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                
                return fileImage;

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.print(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
     }
```

When taking the photograph, I use this code;

```
public void cameraClicked(View view) {

        

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/photoTemp.png");

        try {
            tempFile.createNewFile();
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    this.getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageName() + ".provider", tempFile);
            //install.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work when saving image, it doesn't seem to save anywhere?

EDIT -

If I revert back to why I needed to change, it is all because of this method;

The camera does NOT open when using this method - if it did, I could have left the rest of the file paths etc as they were.

```
public void cameraClicked(View view) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/photoTemp.png");
        try {
            tempFile.createNewFile();
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    this.getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageName() + ".provider", tempFile);
            //install.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: "the app does not crash but the file is not being saved anywhere" -- presumably, it is being saved in the location returned by `getExternalFilesDir(null)`. "It doesn't work when saving image" -- please explain **in detail** what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Apologies - it's not saving anywhere on my device that I can find - launching google photos it's not creating an album or being found anywhere.

Comment: "it's not saving anywhere on my device that I can find" -- it will stored in external storage, under `Android/data/your.application.id.goes.here/files/`, where `your.application.id.goes.here` is your application ID. Files placed in that location are designed for use by your app, not by other apps (e.g., Google Photos).

Comment: Ah! My mistake, I saw it now in 'Files' app on my Samsung device - is there a location I can save to that includes a folder Google Photos can access?

Comment: `Originally, the String filePath was` Well that is a nice path and can be used even today. And on Android 13+ devices without any permission needed.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work when I try leaving it in place, the camera no longer opens - check my edit.

Comment: `tempFile.createNewFile();` Remove that statement. You do not need to create an empty file already. If the uses cancels the picture you are left with an empty file. (If it created a file you know the directory was writable).

Comment: Further you now try to create a file in root of external storage. That will not go. I referred to your first mentioned path in DCIM.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642726/java-io-filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eexist-file-exists-android-11/66645800#66645800) for accessing internal storage on API 30+. Your functions to get internal paths would simply return what you'd get from `getFilesDir()` on these API levels.

i would advise against the linked answer though, *in most cases* - as the permission required is not one easily approved in the PlayStore without good cause.

Instead you could *first create your file in `getFilesDir()` path* and then use SAF to 'export' the file, finally removing it from the previous path if needed.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import android.net.Uri;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;

import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;

private ActivityResultLauncher<String> exportFileIntent;

exportFileIntent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument("text/plain"), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>()

{

@Override

public void onActivityResult(Uri returnData)

{

if(returnData != null)

{

try

{

File f = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + fname);

OutputStream exportStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(returnData);

Files.copy(Paths.get(f.toURI()), exportStream);

exportStream.close();

}

catch(IOException e)

{

// ...

}

}

}

});

exportFileIntent.launch("fname.txt");
```

I am on my phone - I apologize for messed up indentation.

Only critical excerpt provided.

Comment: please be aware that for the try block in the provided code, it would be better to use try with resources since if the try block messes up as code is now, outputstream will not close caysing __memory leak__