# Camera button press - Intent / Creating file not working API 31+

Tags: java, android, camera

When I attempt to access the camera, API 31+, the button is non responsive;

```
public void cameraClicked(View view) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/photoTemp.png");
        try {
            tempFile.createNewFile();
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    this.getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageName() + ".provider", tempFile);
            //install.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If I remove `tempFile.createNewFile();` then the camera opens, but once the photo is taken, the app does not progress to the next page (the editor page for the image taken). It just reverts back to the main menu.
I am guessing this is permission related, as the new file is not able to be created. But I have added permissions as per google docs - and launchtime permissions are given, I checked app permissions and camera access is granted.

EDIT -

I now use this code, and the camera opens;

```
public void cameraClicked(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/photoTemp.png");
        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/photoTemp.png");
        try {
            tempFile.createNewFile();
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    this.getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageName() + ".provider", tempFile);
            //install.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The result method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditorActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("mode", false);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        int i = 0;
                        int j = i;

                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/photoTemp.png");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditorActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("mode", true);
                    //File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/photoTemp.png");
                    intent.putExtra("url", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/photoTemp.png");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
            case 10001:
                if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
                        resultCode, data)) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Matching paths, everything SHOULD work, and seems to work when testing it live in Android Studio, but when I export to .apk to test it as a 'demo install' and try, the camera take a photo and does not progress to `EditorActivity` screen.

EditorActivity has these methods;

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "photoTemp.png", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Comment: You already got an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77699579/trying-to-save-image-using-api-31-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory. You should use the DCIM path. Not try to create a file in root of external storage.

Comment: Place a Toast() in that catch block so the user gets informed about exceptions.

Comment: Added more to this question, to give you an idea what is now happening

Comment: You use two different paths.

Comment: Indeed but I can't seem to write the correct path on the other parts of code, as they are not in the same format for me to reuse on decodefile and the intent parts further down.

Comment: Why not? Pretty simple to use one and the same path. Use only the DCIM path.

Comment: OK I got it working so that it seems to be perfect, however when I export a debug APK it doesn't work, it just goes back to the main menu once the picture is taken using the camera - I have no idea why? It works when connecting to USB in Android Studio and building, but not when I've exported it.
Updated the code to show everything I am now using.

Comment: Further to this, android studio testing of it has he same error, just doesn't progress once photo is taken. Weird how it worked for a short while then suddenly stopped...